# element with dragula directive not draggable in angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dragula

I have a div

```
<div dragula='"bag-one"'>Div1 </div>
```

In controller, the event is triggered but element is not dragging.

```
    $scope
        .$on('bag-one.drag', function (e, el) {
console.log("called");
        })
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you see no errors, just try to add couple lines in the container of dragula.

```
<div dragula='"bag-one"'>
   <span>Row one</span>
   <span>Row two</span>
</div>
```